# Why are my Components not showing when using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, single-page-application

My problem is related to redux. I was making a simple counter application. I copied each step exactly from the redux-toolkit site. I just changed it for myself. But when I run it, no component appeared.

*This project is written in javascript. `@Reduxjs/Toolkit` and `react-redux`
libraries are used.*

Here are the codes I wrote:

This is store:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlvxu.png)

This is index.js:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxkji.png)

This is where I accessed and changed my store data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ2WH.png)

This is Reducer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQR91.png)

This directory structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC6Wa.png)

This is a output screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi1yE.png)

I am waiting for your answers :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the console (Ctrl + Shift + I )
The error message should give you a hint. In your redcer - you are setting initial state incorrect.

```
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: { ...
```

Read more: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice